# Simple filesystem cube

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas

I'm trying to understand cubes so thought I would create a simple datamart to represent my filesystem.

So my question is, if I wanted to create a simple datamart to represent my filesystem, how would it look?

I'm just thinking one fact for the files, and a few dimensions for file extension, maybe a date dimension and few others.

eg
factFiles
dimExtensions

Some guidance/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Personally when i got started out with SSAS the best thing i found to do was run through the examples using Adventureworks. The tutorials are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170208(v=sql.110).aspx You may need to use the dropdown to select the version of sql server you intend to use.

The pre-reqs take you through getting sample data installed. They're actually very good tutorials to follow along with. I went through them when 2005 was the latest version so can't necessarily vouch for the more recent editions but i'm sure they're of equal quality.

Thanks,

Simon